# ReactJs 'map' is Not a Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Try to make Github API fetch To get User GitHub info

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    const { username } = this.props;
    const { clientId, clientSecret, count, sort } = this.state;

    fetch(
      `http://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos?per_page=${count}&sort=${sort}&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (this.refs.myRef) {
          this.setState({ repos: data.conves });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

When I Start render it with map() I get an error that map() is not function!

```js
 const repoItems = repos.map(repo => (
  <div>
    <Link to={repo.html_url} className="text-info" target="_blank">
       {repo.name}
     </Link>
  </div>
 ));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ATmO.png)

Comment: Did you initialize your state? `this.state = { repos: [] };`

Comment: yah 
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      repos: []
    };
  }

Comment: What your error seems to suggest is that repos in state is not an array, its an object probably which is what you might be receiving from api

Comment: You’re probably getting an object from your api call instead of an array

Comment: What is the `conves ` you are trying to access?

Comment: If you go here you don't get any key like `conves`. https://api.github.com/users/${userName}/repos

Comment: conves is probably not an array. Try to log it

Comment: I get it, it's object